# C++ Win32 GUI App, Console prompt overwrites previous logged text after program exit

Tags: c++, winapi, console, cout

Operating System is **Windows 10**.

The application is linked with **/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS** with a console Attached/Allocated and the Input/Output streams redirected like so:

```cpp
void InitConsole()
{
    if (AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS) || AllocConsole()) {
        SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

        FILE* dummy;
        freopen_s(&dummy, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
        freopen_s(&dummy, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        freopen_s(&dummy, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);

        DWORD consoleMode;
        GetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &consoleMode);
        consoleMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
        SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), consoleMode);

        std::ios::sync_with_stdio(true);

        std::wcout.clear();
        std::cout.clear();
        std::wcerr.clear();
        std::cerr.clear();
        std::wcin.clear();
        std::cin.clear();
    }
}
```

This works, the text is displayed with colors and such, however after the program exits, the console prompt overwrites the logged text instead of continuing from where it ended:

[GIF of the Prompt overwriting the logged text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5uxG.gif)

This happens on the *Windows Terminal*, *PowerShell* and *Command Prompt*, as well as the VSCode integrated terminal.

The text is logged using the fmtlib. However `std::cout` and `printf()` behave equally as wrong.

Is there any way to correct this behavior to the more familiar one of the console prompt continuing from where the logged text ended whilst using **/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS**? Like so:

[Image of the expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/forEi.png)

The expected behavior was achieved by using **/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE** without calling the `InitConsole()` function.

Minimum reproducible example: (Link with **/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS**)

```cpp
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    if (AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS) || AllocConsole()) {
        SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

        FILE* dummy;
        freopen_s(&dummy, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
        freopen_s(&dummy, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        freopen_s(&dummy, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);

        DWORD consoleMode;
        GetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &consoleMode);
        consoleMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
        SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), consoleMode);

        std::ios::sync_with_stdio(true);

        std::wcout.clear();
        std::cout.clear();
        std::wcerr.clear();
        std::cerr.clear();
        std::wcin.clear();
        std::cin.clear();
    }

    std::cout << "Test Text 1\n";
    std::cout << "Test Text 2\n";
    std::cout << "Test Text 3\n";

    FreeConsole();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiled as a Windows program, it starts asynchronously - in the background so to speak - and the command prompt comes immediately. It doesn't wait for the program to finish.

I recommend compiling it as a console program if you don't want the command prompt to appear until after the program has finished.